# Program to calculate sin(0.75) close, but not working?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have already posted a question regarding this problem, and have implemented what i've learned from the answers. I'm now at a point where the answers that are printed out on the screen are very close, but incorrect. Here is the code I now have:

```
program taylor
implicit none
integer :: k = 0
real :: y = 0.75
real :: x = 0.75
do while (abs(y - sin(0.75)) > 1E-6)
 k = k + 1
 y = y + ((y * (-x * x)) /( 2 * k * (2 * k + 1 )))
 print *, y
end do
end program taylor
```

I can't seem to spot the error here, why is this not working? The first answer it prints is correct, but then it seems to get progressively lower, instead of closer to the true value. (The do while loop is to ensure the program stops when the absolute value between the calculation and the intrinsic sin function is less than 1E-6). I can see that the program is constantly reducing the final output, and the Taylor series is suppose to alternate between - and +, so how can I write that in my program?

Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, that "sine" variable was an experiment (edited question), i've now removed that and replaced it with "y" in the do while loop and still have the same issue. How can I edit the do while loop to satisfy the condition i'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taylor series uses factorials and power of x.

taylor_sin(x) = sum[0->n] ( [(-1 ^ n) / (2n + 1)!] * x**(2n + 1) )

(Sorry for my poor keyboard math skills...)

```
program taylor
implicit none
integer :: n = 0
real :: fac = 1
real :: y = 0.75
real :: x = 0.75
real :: px = 1
integer :: sgn = -1
integer :: s = 1 
do while (abs(y - sin(0.75)) > 1E-6)
 n = n + 1
 fac = fac * (2 * n) * ((2 * n) + 1)
 px = px * (x * x)
 s = s * sgn
 y = y + ((s /fac) * (px * x))
 print *, y
end do
end program taylor
```

Computing the factorial `fac` in a loop is rather trivial.

To compute x**(2n + 1), compute and keep x**(2n) and add an extra multiplication by x.

I use an integer to compute -1**n since using a real *may* lose precision over time.

[EDIT] silly me... you can save that extra multiplication by x by setting px to 0.75 before the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks your answer has helped a lot. I've implemented what you said, and now it prints out 3 correct values. However, i've implemented a feature that prints out the absolute difference between the result and the intrinsic sin function after each iteration, and after the 3rd and final result it prints, it's saying this absolute difference is about 1.8E-7, which is less than 1E-6, which violates the do while loop. Why is this?

Comment: To be honest, this doesn't affect my program much, I wanted it to do it until the difference is less than 1E-6 which it's technically done. But I'm just wondering why it did it, when it's surely violating the do while loop? thanks @Michaël Roy

Comment: You can't expect the math to stop at the exact value you want.  Especially with floating points, which are but an approximation of reals - an irrational value to boot in this case.. I don't understand what you mean by violating the while loop, which stops correctly when your approximation is less than 1e-6 of the expected value.  That's perfectly normal behaviour for this kind of algorithm.  Convergence is really fast, that's what is important.  You should try computing different sine approximations, and observe the convergence and results obtained.

Comment: You can think of the difference being due to the fact that you have 2 different algorithms being used to approximate the sine: yours and the fortran library's.